# Strict warning and views - site not working

Tags: views, 6

I am using drupal 6 and after moving to php 5.4 or 5.5 from 5.3, I am getting error `"strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_style_default::options() should be compatible with views_object::options() in.... views_plugin_style_default.inc on line 24."`
I tried updating views but does not help. It is not just about warning - Views do not work at all. What can be done in this case? Besides switching to 7.x - it is not an option for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch, it can be found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/893128

I used this one: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/893128-61.views_.strict-warnings-method-declarations-php-5-4.patch but it did not fix everything. In the end I fixed some items manually similar to what is done in the patch where I replace the function arguments that are the problem from $argument to &$argument. (or sometimes the other way around).

Did you already try the latest dev version, because a patch for the issue I mentioned was committed recently, but I don't think a new version was released since then.

Comment: @Bala, thanks for the help, I have edited my answer. May I ask why you downvoted my answer immediately, it was meant as help. the fact I mentioned there is a patch might encourage someone to go look in the issue queue on drupal.org :)

Comment: Hi daften downvote not from me, now your answer looks good!